# Labels disappearing when moved using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using QGIS 3.8.

I created a polygon shapefile. Now I want to label the polygons according to a certain column in the attribute table. No problem so far.

When I manually move the labels some labels disappear. The more labels I move the more labels disappear.

I tried many different things in the label settings as ticking "show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)", "Label every part of multi-part features" or untick "Discouraging labels from covering features".

I have no idea how to solve that problem and would be happy with any ideas. I could also upload the data (but I don't know how to do it).

Answer (score 5):

You need to point to a column of unique values because QGIS is going to store the label override X,Y values to a temporary column and store the changes using unique values for each feature.

If you point to a column that has duplicate values, any label that has that same value will get the X,Y of the label you just moved, which is why you're seeing labels disappear.